# Зуб чеснока или только зубок чеснока?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Допустимо ли употреблять "зуб" вместо "зубок"? В словаре такого примера не нашёл.

Comment: Форма «зубчик чеснока» более в ходу, нежели «зубок».

Comment: @shampar, наверное. Думаю, вопрос регионального употребления.

Comment: Такая замена напоминает употребление нового словечка "ссыль" вместо "ссылка".

Comment: Я сейчас с величайшим удивлением обнаружил, что в некоторых кулинарных рецептах "зубок" тоже встречается. Видимо, да - региональное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только зубок. Или зубчик, но никак не "зуб".

Тут штука такая, что "зубчик" относится к зубцам или зубьям, а не к зубам. 
"Зубок" - чаще все-таки зубы, но и зубцы не исключены.

Так вот дольки чеснока по форме напоминают зубцы, но вряд ли зубы. Легенда о том, что чеснок это ведьмины зубы, - вторична, к этимологии отношение вряд ли имеет.

Что касается выбора между "зубок" и "зубчик", то сказанное даёт некоторое преимущество в праве не первородство второму, зубчику. Но, если судить по нынешнему состоянию, большой разницы в частотности нет, используются как синонимы (даже в пределах одной фразы), различий в стилистической окраске не наблюдается. Разумеется, все - по самому поверхностному анализу, но не думаю, что при более глубоком будут какие-то сюрпризы.